# openlayers: get length of selected feature

Tags: extjs, openlayers

i'm using openlayers and geoExt.

what i have is this:

```
var options = {
        hover : true,
        box : true,
        onSelect : saveToJ
    };

    var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vecLayer, options);
    map.addControl(select);
    select.activate();
```

now in `saveToJ` function i want to get length of selected feature (let's say feature = lineString):

```
function saveToJ(feature) {
    feature.getLength()
...
}
```

gives an error `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getLength'`, but from [this](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.getLength)
i thought i can use it.

So: how can i get a length of selected feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getLength` is a method of `Geometry`, not `Feature`.

So you should write `feature.geometry.getLength()`, see http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.getLength

Comment: great! thanks! while i was waiting for the answer i've made up a function which generates points from feature coords and then generates linestring :) correct solution is much better)